# symfony2: I still can not set cache/ directory permissions (setfacl, umask)

Tags: symfony

I have run this lines:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -Rn -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dRn -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

but my server (apache) can not write in the `cache/` directory... This is the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Unable to create the cache directory
>   (/home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/cache/dev)\n' in
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2471\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2432):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->buildContainer()\n#1
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2212):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer()\n#2
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2243):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()\n#3
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/web/app_dev.php(29):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))\n#4
>   {main}\n  thrown in
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/nataliacanellas/app/bootstrap.php.cache on
>   line 2471

Of course, I installed acl and added this:

```
`UUID=857ea3b1-a007-483c-83be-71f77c6455b7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,acl 0       1
`
```

and remount `/`.

I have also tried this:

```
<?php

umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

inside `app/console`, `web/app_dev.php` and `web/app.php`, but the error is still the same.

Comment: What is the result of `getfacl app/cache`? Is your *apache* running under an unusual username? Did you check if the fs is mounted with `acl`? You can do this by running `mount` and check for the `acl` in the output.

Comment: @ferdynator this is the output: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/9808750

Comment: @ferdynator this is the output of `mount`: https://gist.github.com/Ziiweb/9808946

Comment: Hm. Your permissions are more than you need. Are you running a virtual machine? Maybe vagrant or so?

Comment: @ferdynator no, im on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: got same problem on 13.10

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am quite late in answering this, but seeing as I had the same issues and this thread was one of the first results in Google, I thought I would post my solution here.

**Background**

My Apache2 install runs under the `www-data` group, as evidenced by the output of:

```
    $ ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1
    www-data
```

For reference, I keep my local `/var/www` in Ubuntu 14.04 with group read/write permissions and ownership set to `$USER:www-data`:

```
    $ sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www
    $ sudo chmod -R g+rw /var/www
```

Additionally, I have my `$USER` in the `www-data` group using

```
    $ usermod -aG www-data $USER
```

I set these permissions in order to allow my account write access to `/var/www` for local development purposes.

**Solution**

Foremost, I sought to use `chmod` and `chown` instead of applying the `setfacl` logic presented in the Symfony book. I have no especial reasoning for this besides being more familiar with the `ch*` family of permission commands.

The solution using my approach was simply setting the `app/cache` and `app/logs` directory ownership to `www-data:www-data` by running:

```
    $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data app/cache
    $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data app/logs
```

This ensures Apache2 and PHP have write access to those directories. Checking my `umask`:

```
    $ cd app/cache
    $ umask
    0002
```

This indicates permission bits 0775 and is one `umask` value suggested in the Symfony book when setting permissions without ACL.

A related thread on [granting write permissions to www-data](https://superuser.com/questions/646062/granting-write-permissions-to-www-data-group) may help elucidate further.